# On quotient spaces of affine algebraic groups by conjugate subgroups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $H$ be a closed, connected subgroup of an affine algebraic group $G$.

Then is it true that for every $x\in G$, the quotient spaces $G/H$ and $G/xHx^{-1}$ are isomorphic as varieties ?

Where I am considering $G/H$ as a variety in the usual sense as described in Humphreys, Linear Algebraic Groups, Chapter IV

Comment: Make your last sentence concrete..

Comment: reuns: I think the variety stricture on $G/H$ is very standard ... I have seen it in every book on algebraic groups I've come across so far ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the universal property of quotients of algebraic groups, the composition $G \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Int} x} G \rightarrow G/xHx^{-1}$ induces a morphism of varieties $G/H \rightarrow G/xHx^{-1}$.  Similarly you can obtain a morphism $G/xHx^{-1} \rightarrow G/H$ and check that these are inverse to each other.